# How to change the shape of collider2D according to the sprites in animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I want to change the physics shape of the collider2D When the animations are playing.(Because I'm making a character which is a wolf. And in this situation, merely set the one shape is not enough because the area of foot parts are not the same when in horizontal and vertical directions.)

I have tried to get the physics shape from sprites and change the shape of the collider2D. But I could neither get nor change. The function called GetPhysicsShape returns an int value, which I can't understand. And I can't find a way to change the shape of collider2D with codes.

I have edited the physics shape of sprites. And when I reset the Polygon Collider2D, I found it just became the same shape with the physics shape of sprites. So I also wonder if we could reset the collider2D with codes.(But I found it seemed impracticable. I'm not quite sure.)

Actually, I'm not quite sure if this path is right. I just want to change the shape of the collider2D in real time, corresponding to sprites.

And if it's possible. I want to use only one collider2D. I don't want to set so many colliders. It seems complicated.

Appreciating for your help.